# Navigation Drawer in all activities onNavigationItemSelected event not working

Tags: android

I make a BaseActivity and i override the setContentView and this is BaseActivity code

```
public class BaseActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    }

    @Override
    public void setContentView(int layoutResID)
    {
        DrawerLayout fullView = (DrawerLayout) getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.activity_base, null);
        FrameLayout activityContainer = (FrameLayout) fullView.findViewById(R.id.activity_content);
        getLayoutInflater().inflate(layoutResID, activityContainer, true);
        super.setContentView(fullView);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        Log.i("NAV","nav selected");
        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.activity_container);
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        return true;
    }

}
```

and the xml of the BaseActivity is like this

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    android:id="@+id/activity_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/activity_content"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/navigationView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        app:menu="@menu/activity_side_menu_drawer"/>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

and on the MainActivity i extends this Base like this

```
public class MainActivity extends BaseActivity{

}
```

actually the navigation appears well but the onNavigationItemSelected is not working !!

i tried to Log or Toast Nothing working at all
what is wrong?

thanks in advance.

Comment: Where do you call `setNavigationItemSelectedListener`?

Comment: on the BaseActivity .. so all activities should work the same way

Comment: Then post the code for it. How can we help you if you posted half of your code?

Comment: already posted above called onNavigationItemSelected

Comment: I asked where do you call `setNavigationItemSelectedListener`... That's a method you need to call to set the listener.... You need to call it in order to activate the listener on the activity

Comment: you mean i should call it on the MainActivity or where exactly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to call `setNavigationItemSelectedListener`.

This method needs to be called on your `NavigationView`

Start by getting your `NavigationView` with `findViewById(R.id.navigationView)`

Finally call `navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this)`

This will tell your navigation view that the listeners for item selected is the `BaseActivity`

Comment: one last question .. i already wrote the code that should run when the event fired on the base .. why i should call it on every activity to fire the event

Comment: You can create an abstract method on your base activity. Make your other activities override that method and then just call that method. Every activity will have their own implementation of that method

Comment: does `setNavigationItemSelectedListener` should be call in the `BaseActivity` or in the `MainActivity`?